# How to implement App calls when iPhone is locked like imo, whatsapp and skype?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, voip

I have been trying to integrated VOIP on my application. But not finding a way to implement background app calling functionality. Anybody please let me know how to achieve background calls using VOIP.

Comment: You have to implement push kit https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use VoIP Push and CallKit to handle calls in background or in Inactive  state or locked.

Learn more here...

1. https://medium.com/@yusukek/system-calling-screen-with-callkit-77004b1224e5#.ezwhgdw3h
2. https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit
3. https://developer.apple.com/reference/pushkit